# Change column type in a materialized view

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I have a materialized view based on a table that on which a column type changed. and I'd like to change the column on the materialized view.

I'm aware that a view is based on it's definition but I couldn't find how to updated the select in the definition.

Is the only way to do it to drop the view and re-create it with a new definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not what you were hoping to get, but currently **the only way** to change the query on which a materialized view is based is to drop and recreate it. Still the case in Postgres 10.

[`ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altermaterializedview.html) can only change auxiliary properties. You can also change column *names*, but not data types.

If concurrent access is required and the MV takes a long time to recreate, you might create a *new* MV under a different name, populate it and use it instead of the old one to keep downtime to a minimum - if that's an option.

Related:

- [Replace a materialized view in Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56304/replace-a-materialized-view-in-postgres)